# MySQL ROUND function using round half down instead of half up

Tags: mysql, rounding

So I'm running MySQL version 5.1.4 and I'm trying to select distinct by a rounded value, and it works great except that it rounds numbers like 12.5 to 12 instead of 13. The columns I have tried this on have all been type double. I did a bit of research and saw the default behavior is to round half up so I'm wondering if there is some setting or parameter I need to change or if this is just broken?

Here is my query for reference : 
SELECT DISTINCT ROUND(radius) as radius FROM `arch` WHERE radius != '' ORDER BY `radius` ASC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-rounding.html). Converting the `radius` column to `DECIMAL` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-rounding.html

The half round rule only applies to exact numbers (i.e. Integers and Decimals), for you Doubles the behavior depends on the underlying C library.

I suspect you are going to have to convert the values to DECIMAL to get the desired rounding.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL for exact value types (DECIMAL, INT) employs half up rounding (so `12.5` rounds to `13`).

For approximate types (FLOAT, DOUBLE), MySQL will *typically* use round half even aka bankers rounding (`12.5` rounds to `12`, while `13.5` rounds to `14`).

To get around this, you could add `0.5` to the number before you round, or convert your approximate value type to DECIMAL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROUND(radius+0.1) as radius FROM arch WHERE radius != '' ORDER BY radius ASC
```

Perhaps reduce the modifier further if needed.