# MySQL Round() function for decimal stored in string

Tags: mysql, sql, floating-point, numbers

MySQL version is 5.66.22

When I use `ROUND` function for the decimal numbers stored in varchar I see strange behavior for all .5 numbers

```
Select round(0.5)
1

Select round('0.5')
0

Select round('26.5' + 0.00)
26
```

but

```
Select round(1.5)
2

Select round('1.5')
2

Select round(0.55, 1)
0.6

Select round('0.55', 1)
0.6
```

I checked ROUND function in Oracle DB (12c) it works as expected

```
Select round('0.5') from dual 
1

Select round(0.5) from dual 
1
```

Anybody knows how to explain that ?

The described mysql round() function behaviour causing "rounding" issue in the application. For fixing the issue I use:

```
Select round (CAST('0.5' AS DECIMAL(10,2)))
1
```

I understand that storing numbers in the varchar is bad design but this application was written long time ago and no one wants to refactor the code now

Comment: As expected? ROUND on a string literal is supposed to raise an error.

Comment: Also same results on mysql 5.5

Comment: The real question is why you are storing decimal numbers in a varchar datatype.. Strings types are autocasted in some queries what may cause trouble in some cases.

Comment: It's not mysql causing rounding issues, it's you using a malformed data structure. :-/

Comment: I understand that storing numbers in the varchar is bad design but this application was written long time ago and no one wants to refactor the code now

Comment: Possibly related to this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/204757/12916

Comment: MySQL rounds decimals and floats differently `0.5` is a float `'0.5'` gets cast to a decimal.

Comment: I found part of explanantion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913109/mysql-round-function-using-round-half-down-instead-of-half-up  looks like MySQL allways cast string to double before round() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-rounding.html

Comment: OK. Any numeric operation that involves strings results in conversion to `DOUBLE`. And MySQL seems to round `(DOUBLE) 0.5` as 0. Your workaround is correct.

Comment: @jarlh MySQL in few areas is overdesigned, allows things normally prohibited etc. Maybe this is similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting. The behavior can be explained as follows:

1) MySQL converts strings to floating-point values when used in numeric context ([ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html)):

```
CREATE TABLE test AS (
    SELECT 0.5, '0.5' * 1 AS str_to_numeric
);

DESCRIBE test;

+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| 0.5            | decimal(2,1) | NO   |     | 0.0     |       |
| str_to_numeric | double       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

2) As described in the manual:

> [Rounding Behavior](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/precision-math-rounding.html)
>
> The `ROUND()` function rounds differently depending on whether its
>   argument is exact or approximate:
>
> - For exact-value numbers, `ROUND()` uses the “round half up” rule: A
>     value with a fractional part of .5 or greater is rounded up to the
>     next integer if positive or down to the next integer if negative. (In
>     other words, it is rounded away from zero.) A value with a fractional
>     part less than .5 is rounded down to the next integer if positive or
>     up to the next integer if negative.
> - For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On
>     many systems, this means that `ROUND()` uses the “round to nearest even”
>     rule: A value with any fractional part is rounded to the nearest even
>     integer.

Here are some tests illustrating the final behavior of ROUND function:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   fix DECIMAL(10,2),
   arb DOUBLE
);

INSERT INTO test(fix, arb) VALUES
    (0.5, 0.5),
    (1.5, 1.5),
    (2.5, 2.5),
    (3.5, 3.5);

SELECT fix, ROUND(fix) fix_roundex, arb, ROUND(arb) arb_rounded
FROM test

+------+-------------+------+-------------+
| fix  | fix_roundex | arb  | arb_rounded |
+------+-------------+------+-------------+
| 0.50 |           1 |  0.5 |           0 |
| 1.50 |           2 |  1.5 |           2 |
| 2.50 |           3 |  2.5 |           2 |
| 3.50 |           4 |  3.5 |           4 |
+------+-------------+------+-------------+
```

Your solution, explicitly casting numeric strings to `DECIMAL`, is correct.

Comment: Round("floating-point value") still confusing for me. Why Select round('1.5') = 2 and Select round('2.5') = 2 looks like it's using “round half down” for all even and “round half up” for all odd's

Comment: Yup. What you said is another way of saying "round to nearest even"... avoid an odd number in the last digit.